# Move reference between lists in redux store

Tags: reactjs, angular, redux, ngrx

In my store I have multiple lists of ids which reference to normalized entities. 
It looks something like this:

```
{
  list1: [ 1 ], 
  list2: [], 
  //other lists
  entities: {
    1:{data},
     ... 
 } 
}
```

Users can edit items and can select in which list the item should be. I can't find an elegant way to move the item from one list to another if the user changed the list while editing. 
To move an item I have to remove the item-id from the old list and add it to the new one.

How should I remove the Id from the old list after having written it into the new one? Looking into every list for the Id and if found removing it seems a bit wrong to me.

**EDIT:**

To explain my use case further:
There can be n lists, which are dates, for example "08-17-2016" and the items in it are events. A user can change the date of an event and so the event needs to move from one date to the other.

Answer (score 0):

#### I would simply use `Array.prototype.filter` and check with `Array.prototype.indexOf` in which list this Id is present:

```
function moveOrAdd(idToMove, list) {
  if (list.indexOf(idToMove) > -1) {
    // idToMove was in list so remove
    return list.filter(id => id !== idToMove);
  } else {
    // idToMove wasn't in list so add it
    return [...list, idToMove];
  }
}

// your store then, assuming an array of id to move or delete
[1, 2, 3 ... 2000].forEach(
  index => {
    {
      list1: [...moveOrAdd(index, list1)],
      list2: [...moveOrAdd(index, list2)],
      /// etc...
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: This would be a nice approach, but what if I don't know in which list the id was?

Comment: Interesting but I guess I don't fully understand the use-case. What kind of redux actions would operate so that you don't know what id moves and from what list to another? I guess more details on the use-case may help since I'm sure that is my misunderstanding.

Comment: I don't know the list from which it moves but I DO know the id of the item to move . The lists are dates, for example "08-17-2016" and the items in it are events. A user can move an event from one date to another.

Comment: So according to your answer I would need to handle all lists in the if else? This would be impossible since the amount of lists(dates) can be variable(they could be 2 as well as 2000)

Comment: You didn't tell about the amount of list (2 versus 2000) :smile: it just needs to be adapted in that case.

Comment: You're right, my fault :/... But so your answer seems more or less like I suggested it in my question " Looking into every list for the Id and if found removing it"

Comment: Adapted again my answer. However I think I don't understand what should happen with a 2000 lists scenario (2 lists was clear in my mind). So this is a suggestion but adapt what you need (*add other parameters to `moveOrAdd` function for instance*).

Comment: No I think you did not understand what I meant to say. The number of LISTS can be variable, not the number of ids. So there could be 2000 lists but the Id to move is just one.

Comment: But I think to understand where you want to get

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120929/discussion-between-mackentoch-and-daskus).